# Skipping an Item in a .each loop in Ruby using 'next' method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to iterate through an incoming json and once Im done this is the resultant object.

```
{
  "stairs"=>1,
  "walls"=>4,
  "blinds"=>4,
  "oven"=>1,
  "kitchen"=>1,
  "bedroom"=>3,
  "bathroom"=>2,
  "additional_services"=>[
    #<Hashie::Mash additional_service="stairs" count=1>,
    #<Hashie::Mash additional_service="walls" count=4>,
    #<Hashie::Mash additional_service="blinds" count=4>,
    #<Hashie::Mash additional_service="oven" count=1>
  ]
}
```

I don't want the "additional_services" part to be included in this json. Im trying to use the next method to skip it from the iteration but it just doesnt work.

```
task_details = params['cleaning_task']['task_details']
task_details_hash = Hash.new
task_details.each do |k,v|
  next if task_details['additional_services'] 
  key = k
  value = v
  task_details_hash[key] = value    
end
puts task_details_hash
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: format your code. Proper formatting/indentation is super important. Don't know about you, but I find it very difficult to make sense of this simple code because of broken indentation. If code is any larger, you can easily spend hours of time, trying to find a simple problem, which would've been obvious otherwise.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Exactly. My first thought was : wait, there must be a SyntaxError somewhere.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a better way, already built-in (rails).

```
task_details_hash = task_details.except('additional_services')
```

But, at a first glance, your code should do the job too, if you modify your check slightly

```
# next if task_details['additional_services'] 
next if k == 'additional_services'
```